# how do I mock this error call back in jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

```
send(message) {     
this.test.send(name, message, err => {
     if (err) {
        this.logger.info('error', err);
        return;
      }
      this._logger.info('successfully sent');
   });
  }
```

my test:

testClass.send({value: 'hey'});

```
expect(sendSpy.mock.calls[0][0]).toEqual(name); // this works 
 expect(sendSpy.mock.calls[0][1]).toEqual(message); // this works 
 expect(sendSpy.mock.calls[0][2]).toBe(expect.anything) // this doesnt.
```

How do I assert on the error callback so I cover all the lines ?